# Using Dynamic Repeating Formulas in Excel Templates

Tags: microsoft-excel, salesforce

I have an Excel merge template that compares Actions to Results.  It is used by many different sales people.  For that reason, the length of the spreadsheet can vary.  The users have limited Excel skills, so I need the formulas in the template to automatically repeat until they reach the last row of data.  I've used Conga Composer and inserting `&=&=` in front of my formulas and then substituting `{r}` for the row works fine.  However, I'm now testing out Drawloop, and this doesn't work at all.  Any suggestions?  Below is a simple example.

```
&=&=sum(M{r}:N{r})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the data ranges to Tables.  You can do this by selecting the continuous rows and columns, then going to the Insert ribbon and clicking Table.

Once you have a table, then formulas entered in any row are automatically copied to every row, including new rows.